# The most simple way to split equations, left align them and have a space between them?

Tags: math-mode, align

I have four equations which I want to split, align and make sure there is a space between the equations.

```
\begin{align*} 
    \sum^\infty_{i=1} (3t_{2i-1}+t_{2i})9^{-i} \\
    =\sum^\infty_{i=1} (3t_{2i-1}+t_{2i})3^{-2i}\\
    = \sum^\infty_{i=1} 3^{-(2i-1)} t_{2i-1} + 3^{-2i} t_{2i}\\  
    =\sum^\infty_{i=1} t_i 3^{-i}
\end{align*}
```

I tried using the `align` environment, but it aligns to the right.

I tried using `flalign` but this leaves no space between the equations.

Comment: You've missed a * at `\end{align*}`.

Comment: Just FYI, your question doesn't really seem to be about sharelatex itself, so I added a few more appropriate tags. the fact that you may be using sharelatex to write LaTeX is not relevant, unless your question is specifically about sharelatex itself, how to use it, or some problem you're having with the service

Comment: @audiophiel I took the liberty of adding it

Comment: the thing you're missing is an `&` which is what marks the division between the left-hand side of an equation and the right-hand side.  you need to read some elementary documentation.  try `texdoc amsmath`, for example.

Comment: @Au101 how do you make edits with just one letter? is that a matter of reputation?

Comment: @audiophiel Yes I believe it is. 2k rep users can "[edit *anything* in the system without it going through peer review. Not just your posts - *anyone's posts!*](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*} 
&\sum^\infty_{i=1} (3t_{2i-1}+t_{2i})9^{-i}&& \\
&=\sum^\infty_{i=1} (3t_{2i-1}+t_{2i})3^{-2i}\\
&= \sum^\infty_{i=1} 3^{-(2i-1)} t_{2i-1} + 3^{-2i} t_{2i}\\  
&=\sum^\infty_{i=1} t_i 3^{-i}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

should do what you want: 
[image]

You can play arround with the `&` signs a bit to get exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by not leaving space between the equations, but flalign works fine; see below.  Image at the top is `flalign*`, at the bottom it's `align*`.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*} 
&\sum^\infty_{i=1} (3t_{2i-1}+t_{2i})9^{-i}&\\
&=\sum^\infty_{i=1} (3t_{2i-1}+t_{2i})3^{-2i}&\\
&= \sum^\infty_{i=1} 3^{-(2i-1)} t_{2i-1} + 3^{-2i} t_{2i}&\\  
&=\sum^\infty_{i=1} t_i 3^{-i}
\end{flalign*}
\begin{align*} 
&\sum^\infty_{i=1} (3t_{2i-1}+t_{2i})9^{-i}\\
&=\sum^\infty_{i=1} (3t_{2i-1}+t_{2i})3^{-2i}\\
&= \sum^\infty_{i=1} 3^{-(2i-1)} t_{2i-1} + 3^{-2i} t_{2i}\\  
&=\sum^\infty_{i=1} t_i 3^{-i}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]